# How does a microcontroller provide a frequency higher than its crystal frequency?

Tags: microcontroller, oscillator, frequency, crystal, pll

I have a microcontroller which is connected to an 8MHz crystal.

I have a schematic which has a QSPI flash IC connected to it whose clock is provide by the micro and happens to be 48MHz.

I want to understand how the 8MHz is increased to 48MHz. Is it a PLL which does this? If so how?

How can I determine the maximum frequency that the microcontroller can provide from any of its pins?

Comment: MPC5606S- https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/MPC5606S.pdf

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How does an ARM MCU run faster than the external crystal?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/440471/how-does-an-arm-mcu-run-faster-than-the-external-crystal)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many microcontrollers do have one or more PLL inside them, but also internal clock oscillators. In most complex devices, different peripherals can be clocked with different clock sources as well.

What a PLL does is that it has a oscillator inside it (called VCO) and it uses the crystal (8 MHz in your case) as reference. In this case to get 48 MHz, the VCO output would be divided by 6, and compared that the divided VCO output matches the crystal frequency. This means that VCO output is 6*8 MHz or 48 MHz.

The maximum speed a microcontroller can output on its pins is said in the datasheet.

Comment: A small question, when you say that the VCO output is divided by 6, would it be 8MHz/6 or 48MHz/6? If it is 48MHz/6, then how did the VCO output go to 48MHz in the first place

Comment: That was just an example, but VCO output is 48 MHz and it clocks the MCU. 48 MHz is divided by 6 to get same frequency as the reference crystal, and feedback circuitry compares phase and frequency of both 8 MHz clocks to keep these same. If they are not the same then feedback drives the VCO frequency up or down until they match.

Comment: Could you tell me how we got to the 48MHz in the first place from 8MHz?

Comment: The VCO runs at any frequency within some range and the frequency can be set with control voltage. The control voltage comes from the detector that compares divided output with reference and sets the control voltage. It is a feedback loop.

Answer (score 1):

A [PLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase-locked_loop) or [DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay-locked_loop) is most often used to generate a higher frequency from a lower frequency reference.

The maximum frequency that can be output to a pin will be specified in the datasheet or reference manual. Often you can expose system clocks on a couple of pins (called "Clock-out capability" in STM32-speak) or use timers with PWM (or output compare) on some other pins.